# timeout MIDDLEWARE

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, timeout

Eu estou enfrentando alguns problemas ao tentar criar
um middleware que dê timeout em uma requisição da minha API caso essa
requisição ultrapasse 30 segundos.

- Eu tentei fazer isso de inúmeras maneiras, e evidentemente, pesquisei
  em alguns locais. Infelizmente, não consegui resolver o problema.  Em
  diversas tentativas, eu caia no erro:

ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT

Na minha tentativa atual, em todas as requisições, eu estou caindo no
caso em que a requisição está sendo cancelada.

```js
const express = require('express');
const expressPromiseRouter = require('express-promise-router');

const app = express();
const router = expressPromiseRouter();

async function isTimeOut() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      reject('O tempo para a execução foi excedido.');
    }, 3000);

    timeoutId.unref();
  });
}

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await isTimeOut();
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error); 
  }
});

router.get('/minha-rota', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    return res.json({ message: 'Requisição bem-sucedida' });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

router.get('/minha', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Before res.json');
  return res.json({ message: 'Requisição bem-sucedida' });
});

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Servidor Express rodando na porta 3000');
});
```

A rota /minha-rota deveria dar timeout, enquanto a rota /minha deve executar a requisição normalmente. Porém, ambas as rotas caiem em 'O tempo para a execução foi excedido'

- Outra tentativa:

```js
const express = require('express');
const expressPromiseRouter = require('express-promise-router');

const app = express();
const router = expressPromiseRouter();
const util = require('util');




app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.on('finish', () => {
   req.responseSent = true;
  });
  next();
 });
 
 app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  function isTimeOut() {
   return new Promise((resolve, rejects) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       if (!req.responseSent) {
         resolve(next());
         rejects(res.status(408).json({ error: 'O tempo para a execução foi excedido.' }))
       }
     }, 3000);
   });
  }
  isTimeOut()
 });
 




//rota com demora
router.get('/minha-rota', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    return res.json({ message: 'Requisição bem-sucedida' });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name === 'AbortError') {
      console.log('Requisição cancelada pelo cliente.');
    } else {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
});
// ROTA SEM DEMORA
router.get('/minha', async (req, res) => {
  return res.json({ message: 'Requisição bem-sucedida' });
});

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Servidor Express rodando na porta 3000');
});
```

Essa tentativa, por exemplo, se eu chamo a rota localhost:3000/minha-rota duas vezes seguidas, na segunda vez da o erro ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT, na primeira vez tem o comportamento esperado
ERRO:

node:_http_outgoing:645
throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:490:5)
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:645:11)
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

- Outra tentativa:

```js
const express = require('express');
const timeout = require('connect-timeout');

const app = express();

app.use(timeout('3s'));


//rota com demora
app.get('/minha-rota', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    return res.json({ message: 'Requisição bem-sucedida' });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name === 'AbortError') {
      console.log('Requisição cancelada pelo cliente.');
    } else {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
});

// Rota sem demora
app.get('/minha', (req, res) => {
  return res.json({ message: 'Requisição bem-sucedida' });
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (req.timedout) {
    return res.status(408).json({ error: 'O tempo para a execução foi excedido.' });
  }
  next(err);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Servidor Express rodando na porta 3000');
});
```

Também da o erro:   code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT' ao chamar a minha-rota duas vezes consecutivas. Mas, na primeira chamada, funciona perfeitamente.
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:490:5)
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:645:11)

- Como poderia fazer um timeout middleware que cancelasse uma
  requisição após ela demorar um determinado tempo X?

Answer (score -3):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```js
const timeoutMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  if (res.headersSent) {
    return;
  }
  const timeout = 3000; 
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      res.status(504).send("Timeout");

  }, timeout);

  next();

  req.on("finish", () => clearTimeout(timeoutId));
};
```

Está funcionando. Se alguém tiver uma sugestão de como melhorar aceito. Mas funciona :D.